# mysql_query not using password

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I list the tables in my database?

This is how I'm connecting to the database.

```
echo "Connected:".CreateCheckMySQLConnection()."</br>";
echo "Tables:</br>".ListTables();

function CreateCheckMySQLConnection() {
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($GLOBALS['servername'], $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}//End CreateCheckMySQLConnection
```

Thanks, Luke.

Comment: Simple; you're mixing MySQL APIs. This isn't *gin & tonic*

Comment: Theres different types of API? This is the first time I've worked with PHP and MySQL. Usually I'm using it with Java